# Why the execution thread for inner class, which extends thread, is the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having difficulty understanding the behavior of inner class threads.

I have this simple test program.

```
public class Test {
    private static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public class TestThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void start() {
            System.out.println("in start " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(5000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(5000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }).start();
        }

        System.out.println("new run");
        Test test = new Test();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
            (test. new TestThread()).start();
        }
    }
}
```

When the first for loop runs, the threads behaves as I expected.  Total of 6 threads, main, thread-0, thread-1, thread-2, thread-3, and thread-4.  Thread 0 - 4 are printed out of order as I expected.

The result for second for loop has me confused.

`system.out.println("in start " + Thread.currentThread().getName());`

It always prints out "main," and the threads are executed sequentially.  Why is the execution of the inner class thread carried out by the main thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Don't override `Thread.start()`.  The start method is always called from the thread that is starting it.  You need to override `Thread.run()`.

(See examples in the [`Thread` class' javadoc documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html))

Comment: Thank you.  Now it makes complete sense.  :)

Comment: Or even better [don't extend Thread at all...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `@Override` the `start()` method. You should `@Override` `run()` instead. Then call `start()`.

Comment: Better still if the OP would not override `run()` either, but provide the `Thread` with a `Runnable` _delegate_ instead.